# Android Studio and TDD - How to run tests in a few seconds

Tags: android, junit, gradle, tdd, android-studio

I'm using the current version of Android Studio.
I've set up a gradle project with robolectric and robolectric/gradle-android-test-plugin for testing.
So far I've only written a simple tests that fails (think of it as assertTrue(false)).
Running gradle clean test takes more than half a minute.
How can I run just this one test within a few seconds (max 5 seconds), so that I can do real TDD?

Comment: check where your time is spend, a test just with assertTrue(false) will not need 30 seconds. prof it with a simple time stop at begin and and of your test method.

Comment: as far as I can tell, the time is spent with recompiling the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that the problem was due to a framework that relies on code generation.
In other words, as long as this framework is in use there is most likely no way to work around long generation times.